# Generating x, y, coordinates within polygon/polyline with certain interval in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, xy, point-creation

I need all the x- and y-coordinates with a interval of 500 meters that fit inside a polygon/polyline.

For example I want to generate a CSV file that looks like this:

```
x, y,
10000, 30000
10500, 30000
11000, 30000
11500, 30000
12000, 30000
10000, 30500
10000, 31000
10000, 32000
10000, 32500
```

So It makes a kind of "grid" (maybe this is the wrong word) that fit inside the (polygon/polyline). I want to use these coordinates so I can do calculations on each point (x,y) inside my polygon.

How in QGIS can I make this CSV file? And what is a better word for the "grid" of x,y coordinates that I am trying to make?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, because you probably don't want a CSV but an actual systematic sample point layer, formed from those points, and it actually easier to go straight to the points. encode them with the polygon key value through topological overlay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grid is the correct term. If you have a line layer you need to convert it to polygon.

1. Create a point grid using the polygons extent with 500 m x and y spacing
2. Extract the points inside the polygon with extract by location
3. If you, like in your question, need even 500 m intervals, use Snap points to grid to snap them to 500 m intervals.
4. Add geometry attributes and save output to csv:

You can find all tools by searching the processing toolbox Ctrl+Alt+T

[image]